# Swiper.js Forced Reflow performance issues when responsive

Tags: swiper.js

A question about using swiper.js carousel/slider gallery. I'm getting bad performance issues with "forced reflow" when making the slider responsive.

If the viewport is resized then the forced reflow is extreme. How do I go about debugging this?

Swiper github says this is the best place for asking for support.

I've added example code here.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Wonderfulx/pen/gOpXGOa)

```js
// Just duplicating swiper 20 times
const listing = document.getElementsByClassName("listing")[0];
for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
  let clone = listing.cloneNode(true);
  clone.getElementsByClassName("swiper-container")[0].id = `carousel-${i+1}`;
  document.getElementsByClassName("grid")[0].appendChild(clone);
  newSwiper(i + 1);
}

function newSwiper(i) {
  let swiper = new Swiper(`#carousel-${i}`, {
    initialSlide: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6),
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    }
  });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/css/swiper.min.css');

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.swiper-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.listing {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.listing::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="listing">

    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8aoOSaob.jpg" alt="thumb">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FB5IGMgb.jpg" alt="thumb">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GBpr1JR.png" alt="thumb">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UYqiudHb.jpg" alt="thumb">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BBFBbuA.jpeg" alt="thumb">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tpZvfRn.jpg" alt="thumb">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I spent way too much time trying to fix this problem. Playing with the css over and over. I've come to the conclusion it's swiper.js. Perhaps how things are recalculated somewhere.

I switched the code over the glide.js and no performance problems. There's no lazy loading included so more development time needed to plug that gap.